# Organizing three dimensional data from table into matrix/array form using R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I have a table that looks similar to this

`MUNI YEAR ENTE SALE`
`D101 1995 F001 1000`
`D101 1995 F002 1200`
`D101 1995 F003 1300`
`D101 1996 F001 1000`
`D101 1996 F003 1250`
`D101 1996 F004 1300`
`D101 1997 F001 1000`
`D101 1998 F002 1400`
`D101 1998 F003 1500`
`D102 1995 F001 1000`
`D102 1995 F003 1200`
`D102 1995 F006 1300`
`D102 1996 F001 1050`
`D102 1996 F002 1320`
`D102 1996 F003 1250`
`D102 1996 F006 1350`
`D102 1996 F002 1320`
`...`

It is a sales table where MUNI stands for markets and ENTE stands for firms. The data consists of 7 years, 1200 markets and 200 firms. I would like to reorganize this table into a matrix form such that the dimensions are (rows = MUNI X YEAR, Cols = ENTE) and in each cell there is the value of sale, something like this

`MUNIxYEAR\ENTE F001 F002 F003 F004 ...`
`D101x1995      1000 1200 1300 NA   ...`
`D101x1996      1000 NA   1250 1300 ...`
`...`

I am not sure how to this or the best way to proceed so I get the above-mentioned data organization. I have checked other posts and I believe the way of doing this is to use the command sparseMatrix. However, I don't know how to use it when (1) you have multiple criteria (i.e., two conditions for the rows) and (2) the dimensions of the matrix are string IDs (change them into factors and the get the levels?).

Thanks in advance for any help and guidance.

Comment: Look at package reshape2. I don't know why you believe that `sparseMatrix` is the way to go. Is your data so big that a dense matrix doesn't fit into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xtabs`

For instance:

```
# Set random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)
# Generate 500 rows of random data
my.data = data.frame(MUNI = rep(paste0("D", 101:110), each = 50),
                     YEAR = sample(1990:2000, 500, replace = TRUE),
                     ENTE = sample(paste0("F00", 1:9), 500, replace = T),
                     SALE = sample(1000:2000, 500, replace = T)
                     )

# Create a new column with the string "MUNIxYEAR"
my.data$MUNIxYEAR = paste(my.data$MUNI, my.data$YEAR, sep = "x")

# Call xtabs to get the table!
res <- xtabs(SALE ~ MUNIxYEAR + ENTE, my.data)
```

First lines of the output:

```
          ENTE
MUNIxYEAR   F001 F002 F003 F004 F005 F006 F007 F008 F009
  D101x1990 1339    0    0 1693    0 2831 2779    0    0
  D101x1991    0 1407    0 3619    0    0    0 1254    0
  D101x1992    0    0    0    0 1807    0 1766    0 1657
  D101x1993 1174 1154    0    0 1794    0    0 1218    0
  D101x1994    0 1015 6636    0    0    0 2126    0    0
  D101x1995    0    0    0    0    0 3478 3228 1517    0
  D101x1996    0    0 1304    0    0    0 1505    0    0
  D101x1997    0 1077 1481 1802    0 2494    0    0    0
  D101x1998    0    0 1660 5366 1844    0    0 1006    0
  D101x1999    0 1437    0    0    0    0 1844    0 2394
  D101x2000    0    0 1714    0    0    0 1950 1758 1108
  D102x1990 3761    0 3307 1182    0    0    0    0    0
  D102x1991    0    0    0 1539 2716    0 1716    0    0
  D102x1992 1980    0 1056 1458    0    0    0    0 1641
  D102x1993    0    0 1429    0 1784    0 1114    0    0
  D102x1994    0    0    0    0 1377    0 1038 1000    0
  D102x1995    0    0 1088    0    0 1031 4205 1764    0
  D102x1996    0    0    0    0 1658    0 3559    0    0
  D102x1997    0 1048 2453    0    0 1741    0    0    0
  D102x1998 1427 5139    0 1336    0    0 1372    0 1395
  D102x1999    0    0    0 3957    0 1972    0    0    0
  D102x2000    0 3258    0    0    0 3780    0 3299 1360
  D103x1990    0    0    0 1247 1526    0    0    0 1234
  D103x1991    0 1919    0    0    0    0    0 1704    0
  D103x1992    0 1489    0    0 4428    0 1371    0    0
  D103x1993    0 1477    0    0    0    0 1319    0 1211
  D103x1994    0 2649    0    0 1488    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways and packages to do that. I'm using a "tidyr" package method:

```
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(MUNI = rep(paste0("D10", c(1,1,2,2,3,4)), each = 2),
                YEAR = rep(1999:2000,3),
                ENTE = paste0("F00", c(1,2,3,3,4,5)),
                SALE = sample(1000:2000, 6, replace = T))

df

#    MUNI YEAR ENTE SALE
# 1  D101 1999 F001 1670
# 2  D101 2000 F002 1420
# 3  D101 1999 F003 1985
# 4  D101 2000 F003 1914
# 5  D102 1999 F004 1727
# 6  D102 2000 F005 1195
# 7  D102 1999 F001 1670
# 8  D102 2000 F002 1420
# 9  D103 1999 F003 1985
# 10 D103 2000 F003 1914
# 11 D104 1999 F004 1727
# 12 D104 2000 F005 1195


spread(df,ENTE,SALE, fill=0)    # in case you decide to have each column separately for querying or further grouping in the future

#   MUNI YEAR F001 F002 F003 F004 F005
# 1 D101 1999 1716    0 1516    0    0
# 2 D101 2000    0 1917 1155    0    0
# 3 D102 1999 1716    0    0 1259    0
# 4 D102 2000    0 1917    0    0 1291
# 5 D103 1999    0    0 1516    0    0
# 6 D103 2000    0    0 1155    0    0
# 7 D104 1999    0    0    0 1259    0
# 8 D104 2000    0    0    0    0 1291


df2 = spread(df,ENTE,SALE, fill=0)
unite(df2, "MUNIxYEAR", MUNI,YEAR, sep = " x ")   # if you want to combine columns

#     MUNIxYEAR F001 F002 F003 F004 F005
# 1 D101 x 1999 1716    0 1516    0    0
# 2 D101 x 2000    0 1917 1155    0    0
# 3 D102 x 1999 1716    0    0 1259    0
# 4 D102 x 2000    0 1917    0    0 1291
# 5 D103 x 1999    0    0 1516    0    0
# 6 D103 x 2000    0    0 1155    0    0
# 7 D104 x 1999    0    0    0 1259    0
# 8 D104 x 2000    0    0    0    0 1291
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xtabs` function can help reformat your data into a 3 dimensional array and then the `ftable` function can flatten it to the 2 dimensional table.

Other options would be the reshape2 or plyr packages (and probably others as well).